# How do I reduce the "touchpad mouse movement" area on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, mouse, touchpad

Whenever I click the left or right button on the touchpad, the mouse cursor moves a bit. This sometimes has the effect that when I for example try to click a button, the mouse cursor is moved and I end up clicking next to the button.

The computer it concerns is a [Asus Zenbook UX303LB](https://www.asus.com/sa-en/Notebooks/ASUS_ZENBOOK_UX303LB/gallery/).

The touch pad has two buttons. If I press them, there's a distinct "click" sound, but if I press them softly there's no click and I can move the mouse cursor.

What I would like to do somehow is decrease the area of the touchpad where "mouse move" is intercepted and just have the left/right buttons enabled in that area.

[Here's another thread asking the same thing for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221664/how-to-tune-touchpad-for-smaller-area). I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Control Panel>Mouse>Device Settings tab, depending on what driver is installed if you can adjust the sensitivity area or not.